# PTIJ: Should I wait for the next Bet Hamikdash to buy marble?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've been waiting for the next Bet Hamikdash to decorate my kitchen counter tops. Marble is beautiful and durable, but very expensive.

I had heard that when the next Bet Hamikdash comes, there will be a dramatic increase in קרבנות - carbonate. Marble is a carbonate. So, I'm hoping that the increase of carbonates, in general, may decrease the price of marble.

Is this true? Does it makes sense for me to wait?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Perhaps קרבנות should be understood as (HCO3)-, or as NaHCO3? If so, that would take marble out of play.  I'll have to do some research on this.

Comment: @Codes Why bicarbonate and not regular carbonate, (CO3)2-, or even carbonite, (CO2)2-?

Comment: @DonielF: I looked up the context of קרבנות.  My earlier comment is inaccurate; marble (CaCO3) is proper.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the carbonate part, but the plentiful marble part is definitely true. The Rambam even opens Mishneh Torah with this idea ([Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah 1:1)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi):

> יְסוֹד הַיְסוֹדוֹת וְעַמּוּד הַחָכְמוֹת לֵידַע: שיש שָׁם מָצוּי רִאשׁוֹן

Translation: The foundation of foundations and firmest pillar of all wisdom is to know: that marble there is found first.

What the Rambam means is that "there", meaning "in Shamayim", marble is found first [in terms of quantity], meaning marble is plentiful in Shamayim.

As we all know, Beit Hamikdash will come down from Shamayim, as Rashi says ([Sukkah 41a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.41a.11?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sukkah.41a.11.1&lang2=en&w2=all&lang3=en)):

> אי נמי...מקדש העתיד שאנו מצפין בנוי ומשוכלל הוא יגלה ויבא משמים שנא' (שמות ט״ו:י״ז) מקדש ה' כוננו ידיך:

Translation: Or too...the Mikdash of the future that we await for, it'll be built and highly advanced, it will appear and come from Shamayim, etc.

And Ramchal says in [Mesillat Yesharim ch. 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Messilat_Yesharim.1.28?vhe=Shechem_Messilat_Yesharim&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ולשבור כל המחיצות המפסיקות בינו לבין קונו, הן הנה כל עניני החומריות והתלוי בהם, עד שימשך אחריו...ממש כברזל אחר אבן השואבת.

Translation: And to break all the partitions that divide between him and his Maker, so will all these materials and such, until they shall be draw after him, much like an iron is drawn after a magnet.

Meaning that when the partition between us and Hashem is broken, all of the heavenly material-stockpile will drop out of the sky and come to us. And that, of course, will happen when the Beit Hamikdash will descend from the sky by busting a hole through the clouds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn’t the availability of קרבנות due to changes in supply, but rather the availability due to changes in using it.  Marble, being אבן, will be in high demand as a building material (well, *higher* demand).  As per Psalm 118:

> אֶבֶן מָֽאֲס֣וּ הַבּוֹנִ֑ים הָֽ֜יְתָ֗ה לְרֹ֣אשׁ פִּנָּֽה

Marble is a metamorphic rock (source: any geology reference), and as such its supply increases only in geological time frames.  The higher demand of the (relatively) fixed amount will cause scarcity to rise.

So you should redo your kitchen counter tops now before the price goes up.

Moreover, marble is an excellent choice for the counter tops.  What is a kitchen for, but to prepare food?  What is food for, but to serve at Shabbat and Festivals?  And what are those for, but to fulfill the mitzvah of hachnasat orchim?  Rav Dimi and Rav Judah emphasize the importance of hachnasat orchim. (Shabbat 127a)  And marble (as well as granite) aid this through hiddur mitzvah, as said by the חכם חמור, Bartholomew ben Simp:

> .אבן זקן טוב. לא מנצח אבן